# URL: XML parsing error : not well formed

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have this error:

```
XML parsing error : not well formed
Location : http://127.0.0.1/localwebsite/map-control-event-type-criteria.php?=&eP=chose&tP=pub_beer&aP[0]=eating&aT=washington
Number of line 1, Column 2 :
```

The source code seems to be correct: I get this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <markers><marker name="the name" address="the adress" lat="46.187424" lng="8.717437" id="1" town="washington"/></markers>
```

The php code of the page looks like this:

```
    <?php
    require 'inc/bootstrap.php';
    require_once 'inc/db.php';

    $db = app::getdatabase();

    $evtpar=$_GET['eP'];
    $typepar=$_GET['tP'];
    $critpar=$_GET['aP']; 
    $townURL=$_GET['aT'];

    // some php code to test the validity of URL parameters

    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 


    $result=$db->query("SELECT name.....)->fetchall(); 

    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    $i=0;
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
       $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
       $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
       $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row->name);
       $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row->address);
       $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row->lat);
       $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row->lng);
       $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row->inf_id);
       $newnode->setAttribute("town", $row->town);

       $i++;
    }   

     echo $dom->saveXML();
```

How can i know where the problem comes from?

Does **Number of line 1** means that the problem comes from the URL or the following code?

**EDIT : Files before the code above:**

Before arriving to the URL I have to previous code:

```
    File1 php:
    $mapDisplay='EventCritType';

    File2 included in File1:

    <?php if($mapDisplay=='EventCritType'): 
    echo     $Map->mapeventcrittypeview($town,$eventparam,$typeparam,$activityparams,$lat,$lng,13); 
    endif; ?>

    file3 = Map Class:

    public function mapeventcrittypeview($town,$eventparam,$typeparam,$activityparams,$lat,$lng,$zoom)
    {

        $evtparam=http_build_query(array('eP'=>$eventparam));
        $tpparam=http_build_query(array('tP'=>$typeparam));
        $actparam=http_build_query(array('aP'=>$activityparams));
        $city=http_build_query(array('aT'=>$town));

        $url="/localwebsite/map-control-event-type-criteria.php?=&$evtparam&$tpparam&$actparam&$city";

        include('inc/map-script.php');

    }

    File4= map-script.php

    script type="text/javascript">

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?= json_encode($lat); ?>, <?= json_encode($lng);?>),
          zoom: <?php echo json_encode($zoom); ?>,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

      downloadUrl(<?= json_encode($url); ?>, function(data) {
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
        var town = markers[i].getAttribute("town").toLowerCase();
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
        createMarker(point, id, town, html, i, map);

      }
      });
    }

    ....

    </script>

    File5= map-control-event-type-criteria.php

    <?php
    require 'inc/bootstrap.php';
    require_once 'inc/db.php';

    $db = app::getdatabase();
    $evtpar=$_GET['eP'];
    $critpar=$_GET['aP']; 
    $townURL=$_GET['aT'];

    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Number of line 1 means that the problem comes from the URL or the following code?

It means the data returned by that URL.

When I test your code with XMLlint it says:

> test.xml:1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

The XML declaration must be the **very** first thing in the document.

You have spaces before it, which are not allowed.

Comment: Thx @Quentin for your help. As I a m not completely sure to understand I edited my post with a sample of how the php code looks like. Is it the  header("Content-type: text/xml"); that should be the first thing in the document?

Comment: @michltm — That should be in the PHP code before you start outputting the XML at all. The XML declaration is the thing starting `<?xml`. Remove all the spaces before it.

Comment: ok I will try to find these spaces and will come back to the answer as soon as I found them.

Comment: I'm still in the process of finding it! I have a few php files calling php files before arriving to the php file here. I will try to formulate all this properly.

Comment: I have to say that I am a bit lost to find where the space could come from. For this reason I edited the post with the sequence of code that ends to the last file with the URL.

Comment: Ok after hours and hours and hours of search, I think I found where the space was. Some files where saved in UTF-8 and some other in UTF-8 without BOM. It seems like encoding all files to UTF-8 without BOM removed some space somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

If that not solve the problems, you can review the code, if you put your code i can help you.

Comment: UTF-8 is the default. Why would specifying it explicitly help?

Comment: Because I try to process the XML in a XML validator and without this tag, that validator not validate the XML